# Why can I not trade some gear in DDO sometimes?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons-online

One of my friends is doing item deconstruction for our group and I've found that some of the items I tried to trade are resulting in a fail message.  These items are not bound on acquire/equip.  In fact, we seem to have been able to trade them after a period of time.

The items do not appear to be class specific or use specific.  They are deconstructable.

Is this just a bug or is there a reason why we can't always trade?

UPDATE: Screen attached w/ item and error message.  I am 100% sure I was never wearing this item as well.
[image]

Comment: Your question is too nonspecific for an exact reason. You may want to read up on how trading is suppose to work on DDOwiki (- http://ddowiki.com/page/Trade -). Chances are the specific item is bound in some way or labeled as "not auctionable, not mailable, not tradable".

Comment: Screenshots of the items will help.

Comment: To clarify, I am 100% sure they are not bound because, I googled trading, read a bit, searched for an open bug on google, searched for an open bug here, then we tried one more time (same way) and were able to trade.  Only 10 or so of the items we attempted to trade were impacted as well.  More than 10 others I was able to trade on initial attempt.  I will however get a screen next time it occurs, as requested.  Honestly, I was intending to post items as well as the exact non-trade message but then the trade went through.

Comment: @Nelson Screen up, maybe you'll see something I don't.

Comment: @ShoeMaker Added a screen, maybe you see something I don't.

Comment: Are there more detailed errors in the chat box? I don't remember if trade errors show up in any of the System channels. Also, I remember DDO has trade amount limits over a period of time because each trade is tracked, but I remember them telling you more info than simply 'trade failed'

Comment: Trades can fail on the other end too.  It may not be the item, but the receiver's inventory is full of has some restriction.